# How to load territorial maps on QGIS from web?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, qgis-plugins, google-earth

Is it possible to use QGIS like Google Earth?

I need to draw simple shapes on territorial maps.
I would like to do that without using multiple files for each part of the Earth.

I use QGIS 1.8, but I can upload to the lastest version if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Openlayers plugin (http://hub.qgis.org/projects/openlayers/wiki) which introduces OpenStreetMap, Google Maps, and Yahoo Maps as basemaps. See these blogs and youtube videos (http://www.digital-geography.com/qgis-plugins-openlayers/#.VEP5-cnYff0; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6N3h4KQW_XQ) for information. Or you can use ESRI's basemapping, as explained in this blog (http://ieqgis.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/adding-esris-online-world-imagery-dataset-to-qgis/). I would strongly recommend you look at the QGIS User Guide for information on Openlayers and digitising. You should use the latest stable version of QGIS.